# Magento 2 / Custom Config Field Array Mapping

Tags: php, magento, mapping, backend, magento2

hope your will have the time to help me.
On any circumstances my Magento 2 Array Mapping will not write selected="selected" to my field. Getting crazy about this.
The Data will be saved and fetched correct.

Big thanks to your help.

Version: Magento 2.2.2

/app/code/Sumedia/Switcher/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Form/Field/Group.php

```php
<?php

namespace Sumedia\Switcher\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field;

class Group extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * Store constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager $storeManager
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager $storeManager,
        array $data = []
    ){
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function _toHtml(){
        if(!$this->getOptions()){
            $groups = $this->storeManager->getGroups();
            foreach($groups AS $row){
                $this->addOption($row->getGroupId(),$row->getName());
            }
        }
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

    /**
     * @param string $value
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setInputName($value){
        return $this->setName($value);
    }

}
```

/app/code/Sumedia/Switcher/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Form/Field/Groupmap.php

```php
<?php

namespace Sumedia\Switcher\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray;

class Groupmap extends AbstractFieldArray
{
    /**
     * @var \Sumedia\Switcher\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\Group
     */
    protected $renderer;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getRenderer()
    {
        if(!$this->renderer){
            $this->renderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'Sumedia\Switcher\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\Group',
                '',['data' => ['is_renderer_to_js_template' => true]]);
        }
        return $this->renderer;
    }

    protected function _prepareToRender()
    {
        $renderer = $this->getRenderer();
        $this->addColumn('store',[
            'label' => __('Store'),
            'renderer'=>$renderer
        ]);
        $this->addColumn('name',[
            'label' => __('Name')
        ]);
        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add');
        parent::_prepareToRender();
    }

    protected function _prepareArrayRow(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
        $store = $row->getStore();
        $options = array();
        if($store){
            $options['option_'.$this->getRenderer()->calcOptionHash($store)] = 'selected="selected"';
        }
        $row->setData('option_extra_attrs',$options);
    }

    public function renderCellTemplate($columnName)
    {
        if($columnName == 'store'){
            $this->_columns[$columnName]['class'] = 'input-text required-entry validate-number';
            $this->_columns[$columnName]['style'] = 'width:50px';
        }
        return parent::renderCellTemplate($columnName);
    }

}
```

/app/code/Sumedia/Switcher/Model/Adminhtml/System/Config/Groupmap.php

```php
<?php

namespace Sumedia\Switcher\Model\Adminhtml\System\Config;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value;

class Groupmap extends Value {

    public function beforeSave(){
        $data = array();
        $value = $this->getValue();
        if(is_array($value)) {
            foreach($value AS $_data){
                if(!isset($_data['store']) || !isset($_data['name'])){
                    continue;
                }
                $id = uniqid();
                $data[$id] = array('store' => $_data['store'],'name' => $_data['name']);
            }
        }
        $this->setValue(serialize($data));
        return $this;
    }

    public function afterLoad(){
        $value = @unserialize($this->getValue());
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $data = array();
            foreach($value AS $id => $_data){
                $data[$id] = array('store' => $_data['store'], 'name' => $_data['name']);
            }
            $this->setValue($data);
        }
        return $this;
    }

}
```

/app/code/Sumedia/Switcher/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>    
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="sumedia" translate="label" sortOrder="100">
            <label>Sumedia</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="sumedia_switcher" translate="label" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1">
            <class>seperator-top</class>
            <label>Switcher</label>
            <tab>sumedia</tab>
            <resource>Sumedia_Switcher::config</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" showInDefault="1">
                <label>General</label>
                <field id="enabled" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
            <group id="store_switch" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" showInDefault="1">
                <label>Store Switch</label>
                <field id="enabled" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>

                </field>
                <field id="use_mapping" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Use Mapping</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="mapping" translate="label comment tooltip" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Mapping</label>
                    <frontend_model>Sumedia\Switcher\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\Groupmap</frontend_model>
                    <backend_model>Sumedia\Switcher\Model\Adminhtml\System\Config\Groupmap</backend_model>                        
                </field>
            </group>                
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Comment: Any Solutions about not write `selected="selected"` in the field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have reload all needed methods with your data, but there you have an issue in **getRenderer** method in **Sumedia\Switcher\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\Groupmap** class, try to change **'is_renderer_to_js_template'** to **'is_render_to_js_template'**

I had the same issue during development custom module couple days ago and found a solution only after reviewing magento's core code (catalog inventory module's code) =)